# How to set frame of view constrained exclusively in code

Tags: xcode, constraints, autolayout

I think I've read that when creating and constraining views exclusively in code it's acceptable to use `[NSView -init]` rather than the designated initialiser `[NSView -initWithFrame:]`. I assumed this was correct and began to construct my interface accordingly: all views fully constrained, but none with an explicit frame rectangle. Everything seemed to be working fine, and I guessed that under the hood cocoa did all the necessary frame-setting calculations. I then attempted to add a `tracking area` to one of my views; it failed, and after debugging I realized it was because my view had neither a frame nor a bounds.

Is the suggestion that `[NSView -initWithFrame:]` should be avoided when creating/constraining in code incorrect? Or is their a way to make cocoa generate the view's frame based on it's constraints? I've no problem adding constraints in code, but I'm keen to avoid the need to deduce all of my view's frame rectangles.